# Фэнфикшн как явления инернет-литературы.

Tags: общие-вопросы

Сейчас в интернете распространено такое явление как фэнфикшн — продолжения или альтернативные сюжеты, написанные поклонниками произведения. Признаться честно, я тоже люблю этот жанр — встречаются очень хорошие, серьезные и талантливые произведения. Но мне приходилось выдерживать множество баталий на тему "зачем нужен фэнфикшн". И, увы, очень большое количество фанфикописцев заявляют, что жанр этот нужен только для того, чтобы, пардон, удовлетворять свои сексуальные фантазии. И удивленно спрашивают: а зачем еще писать? А когда я сказала, что это не так, что интересно просто писать о героях и ставить их в такие ситуации, которых не было в основном произведении, они просто не понимают. А еще этот слэш ("произведения", где "спаривают" персонажей мужского пола), от которого тошнит.
Хотелось бы знать мнение уважаемой общественности по поводу такого явления как фэнфикшн, а еще можно ли считать фэнфикшном официально вышедшие продолжения книг, написанные другими авторами, или фильмов, снятых другими режиссерами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда узнала о явлении, заинтересовалась и пошла активно читать -- любимые герои же. Но быстро наелась. Потому что, как правило, качество так себе, не выдержан ни характер, ни дух, ну и, как Вы верно подметили, в основном целью является не искусство, а сублимация (хотя не сказала бы, что сами авторы так позиционируют ФФ, -- они-то видят себя творцами). И неприятно, когда любимых героев заставляют поступать вопреки их натуре и здравому смыслу. Даже когда уровень высок и дух оригинала выдержан, от вторичности "осадок остаётся". То есть могу признать право на существование таких фиков (наверное), но читать не хочу. А вот юмористические (и пародийные) не слишком большого объёма мне нравятся. Если смешные, конечно.
Кстати, в Вашем вопросе впервые вижу написание через Э. Мне всегда встречалось только "фанфикшн" (или "фанфикшен").

Comment: На самом деле, есть фанфики ОЧЕНЬ сильные, где характеры раскрыты лучше и глубже, чем в оригинале. Их не так много, но они есть. И там совсем не сублимация.

Comment: Ну это само собой, в любом жанре есть шедевры. Но в некоторых их найти особенно сложно) От конкретного фэндома, опять же, многое зависит.

Answer (score 3):

Почти не сталкивался. Но поскольку спрашивают у общественности, а не у знатоков, то выскажу мнение. Как и в любой литературе, дело не в жанре, а в содержании и качестве текста.  
А вообще вопрос упирается в то, можно ли считать данное произведение самостоятельным.
Те, что знаю (продолжения "12 стульев", "Волшебника Изумрудного города" и проч), написаны задолго до интернета, ни о каком ФФ тогда и не слыхивали. В целом они сильно уступают исходному произведению.  
Исключения - пародии. Например, первые вещи Нестора Бегемотова со товарищи (не подумайте чего личного).

Answer (score 0):

Я лично употребляю слово "фанфик". В своё время и сам оскоромился – написал поэму на тыщу строк под впечатлением книг Оксаны Панкеевой (предварительно испросив дозволения). Вещица получилась ужасной как по форме, так и по содержанию, но интернет-сообщество фанов творчества Панкеевой её слопало. Фанфик имеет один существенный недостаток – его трудно понять в отрыве от основного произведения. К примеру, я снабдил своё творение синопсисом ( http://www.ritminme.ru/strannoe-korolevstvo/9-dyadya-styopa-i-kamilla1 ), долженствующим заменить читателю знакомство с основным произведением. Но синопсис получился отнюдь не краткий... В общем, по диагонали просмотреть можно – и дальше не читать.

Почему люди пишут фанфики? Как шутят поклонники Д-Р. Толкиена, 6-я фаза "толкинутости" – "Не так всё было, профессор!" Т.е. человек настолько проникается миром понравившегося ему писателя, что сам начинает писать в том же духе, но по-своему. В основном фанфики несерьёзны, порой издевательские. Но случаются и удачные. Правда, тогда кричат о плагиате, а правоверные фаны рвутся бить морду покусившемуся на святое...

Касательно слеша... Попробуйте опубликовать что-либо на литературном портале "Неизвестный гений". В сравнении с тамошним перечнем сексуальных непотребств, наличие/отсутствие которых должен задекларировать автор, вопрос "Эликировали ли Вы когда-либо машек силически?", заданный герою произведения Р.Шекли "Потолкуем малость", покажется детским лепетом. А на портале "Мастерская писателей" умение писать (в том числе и во всём приведенном спектре извращений) коллективно оттачивается. О, времена, о, нравы...  ;)
Но к фанфикам это особого отношения не имеет – мастера и мастерицы клавиатуры пишут подобные вещи и под влиянием собственной Музы.